# Show all ControlTipText's in a UserForm on pressing 'Alt'

Tags: excel, vba, tooltip, userform

I'm trying to add ControlTipText's to all MSForms.Control in all Userforms, that can be displayed.

Once all of them are Added, I want to Show all ControlTipText's on pressing 'Alt', so I can easily edit the Controltips on the Excel-Sheet.

Taking Baby-Steps, I first 'tried' to instantly make the ControlTip Visible when adding the Value to it.

What I have now is:

```
Dim tips As Worksheet
Set tips = Worksheets("CONTROLTIPS")

Dim i As Integer
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control

i = 0
For Each ctrl In uf.Controls        
    ctrl.ControlTipText = tips.Cells(i + 3, 2).Value        
   ' ctrl .... ("TIPTEXT").Visible = True ?!?        
    i = i + 1        
Next ctrl
```

Comment: What are you getting stuck on exactly? You cannot set control tip texts (in)visible

Comment: Is it even possible to make all Control tip Texts visible on pressing a single button? So it kinda Looks like in Excel, when you press ALT there?

Comment: `I want to Show all ControlTipText's on pressing 'Alt'` You can programatically show the control tip text of only one control at a time. You cannot show all.

Comment: You can show all the tip text one by one in a loop by incorporating a delay if that helps?

Comment: How would showing the controltiptexts with a delay look like?

Comment: Before I answer that, I see 2 questions in your above questions `1` Show Control Tip Text in a loop as soon as they are created `2` Show control tip text when the alt is pressed. Which one is it?

Comment: 2. one would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to show the tooltip of a control. The only way is to simulate the `mouse hover` using APIs. Here is a very basic example. Feel free to amend it to suit your needs.

**Prep**:

1. Create a blank userform
2. Place a commandbutton on the userform and set it's control tip text to whatever you want.

**Logic**:

When the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is pressed, move the mouse over the relevant control thereby triggering the control tip text

**Code**

Paste this code in the userform

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "Gdi32" _
(ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ClientToScreen Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
(ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long

Private Const Xindex = 88
Private Const Yindex = 90

Private Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

'~~> Trap the Alt key in the keydown eveent
Private Sub CommandButton1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 18 Then MoveMouseOnTopOf Me, CommandButton1
End Sub

'~~> Simulate mouse hover
Public Sub MoveMouseOnTopOf(frm As Object, ctl As Object)
    Dim P As POINTAPI
    Dim usrfrmHwnd As Long
    Dim hDC As Long
    Dim X As Double, Y As Double

    hDC = GetDC(0)
    X = 72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, Xindex)
    Y = 72 / GetDeviceCaps(hDC, Yindex)
    ReleaseDC 0, hDC

    P.X = (ctl.Left + (ctl.Width \ 2)) / X
    P.Y = (ctl.Top + (ctl.Height \ 2)) / Y

    usrfrmHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    ClientToScreen usrfrmHwnd, P

    SetCursorPos P.X, P.Y
End Sub
```

You can read and understand about the APIs used above in the [AllAPI](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php) site.

Comment: Very nice implementation. Works a bit clunky but it does what it should do.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to Show all ControlTipText's on pressing 'Alt'

As far as I can tell, this seems to be the reason for you starting this thread.

The values from control tips are stored in the `.ControlTipText` function. AFAIK the `ALT` button will not show all control tips, nor is there a similar alternative. What you CAN do, is show all control tips together with their respective controls in a message box:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        txt = txt & ctrl.Name & ": " & ctrl.ControlTipText & vbNewLine
    Next ctrl
    MsgBox txt
End Sub
```